# Issue assigning an CSS attribute to a HTML element from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a carousel (I know there are tons of snippets ready to copy & paste) by my own. I'm trying to use a setTimeout That changes the background image every 4 seconds, but there's something wrong and I haven't been able to figure it out. I'd like to find a solution using only javascript.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="divi"></div>
```

this is the Javascript:

```
var divi = document.querySelector(".divi");    

srcArr = ["https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300","https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300","https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300"];    

var iter = 0;

setInterval(function () {

    if(iter == (srcArr.length)){
        return; 
    }

    else{

        divi.attributes.style.backgroundImage =  "url('" + srcArr[iter] + "')";

        console.log(divi.attributes.style.backgroundImage)

        iter++;
    }

}, 4000);
```

This is the CSS

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0
}

.divi{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #d3d33f;
}
```

Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The DOM has no `.attributes.style` property.

Comment: yes, I removed the .attributes and worked.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `attributes` property, you should use `style` directly:

```
divi.style.backgroundImage = ...
```

Demo:

```js
var divi = document.querySelector(".divi");    

srcArr = ["https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300","https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300","https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300"];    

var iter = 0;

setInterval(function () {

    if(iter == (srcArr.length)){
        return; 
    }

    else{

        divi.style.backgroundImage =  "url('" + srcArr[iter] + "')";

        iter++;
    }

}, 4000);
```

```css
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0
}

.divi{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #d3d33f;
}
```

```html
<div class="divi"></div>
```